# DefaultIfEmpty Still Throwing Exception Sequence Contains No Matching Element

Tags: c#, linq, defaultifempty

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public static string MyMethod(string myParameter)
{
    var defaultProperty = new Validation() {IDNumber = "ID Number Not Found", Logon = "ID Number Not Found" };
    try
    {
        return lstLogons.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultProperty).Single(x => x.IDNumber == myParameter).Logon;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(exception.Message, myParameter);
    }
}
```

When testing, I am giving `myParameter` a value that I know doesn't exist, so I want to be able to give a default value for these types of situations.  But, instead it just throws an exception:

> Sequence contains no matching element

I know it doesn't contain the element I am searching for.. hence the need/want for a default value.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Unless `myParameter` is `"ID Number Not Found"`, that exception is logical.

Comment: please provide more code. theres not enough information. it is your `Single` call however.

Comment: @DanielA.White that's literally all of my code dealing with this problem.. Basically, if I took `DefaultIfEmpty` out of the lambda.. and just had `lstLogons.Single(x => x.IDNumber == myParameter).Logon;`.. I don't want exceptions thrown if `myParameter` cannot be found.. I just want a default value.

Comment: Your `defaultProperty` does not have an `IDNumber` which will match `myParameter`, hence `.Single()` throws.

Comment: whats `lstLogons`? how does that related to a "defaultProperty".

Comment: @DanielA.White `lstLogons` is a list of `Validation` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are calling `Single()` after that, and `DefaultIfEmpty()` will return collection with just one item in it and calling `Single()` means that there will always be always one item in it with the criteria you specified and it didn't matched, what you need here`SingleOrDefault()` which will not throw exception if no matching item found, insead it will return `null`.

> I want to return a default

you can create a local variable for that with default value:

```
var logon = String.Empty;

var result =  lstLogons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IDNumber == myParameter);
if(result!=null)
    logon = result.Logon;

return logon;
```

Comment: " and DefaultIfEmpty() will return collection with no items in it" - no it won't. It'll return a collection with a single element (the default value for the type) if the source is empty... hence the name. However, the overload of `Single` accepting a predicate won'tt match that...

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad, thanks for the correction, updated to reflect that :)

Comment: When running this, is there even a purpose to use the `defaultProperty` when using `SingleOrDefault`?  If `SingleOrDefault` returns a null value without the use of `DefaultIfEmpty`.. then there should be no use for creating `defaultProperty`?

Comment: valid point @GTown-Coder adjusted the code

Comment: What if I just did `return lstLogons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IDNumber == myParameter).Logon`?  That should either return `null` or an actual `Logon`? What's the purpose of creating another object, (`logon`), when I could just return the value in 1 line?

Comment: if `SingleOrDefault` returns `null` then accessing `Logon` would cause run-time error @GTown-Coder and we are not micro-optimizing the code for OP, the purpose is to outline the issue and provide the working solution.

Comment: Ahhh understood.  I was thinking of it as just one whole line being executed simultaneously.. and wasn't thinking that `SingleOrDefault` is ran first and then the `Logon` is retrieved.  Early morning.. need more caffeine.  Thank you for your assistance.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: no worries, take a cup of coffee ;) glad to help @GTown-Coder